# Why is my div vertically centering inside of the page instead of it's parent div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get all my page content to vertically center on my website. Currently going through tablet/mobile versions, and there is lot of empty space on the bottom half of the text, so I'd like everything to be centered vertically. The issue I'm having is that when I use the transform 'trick' (it's in my media query code on .about-content), it lines up in the middle of the page instead of the parent div, .about-right.

What am I doing wrong here? The more applicable CSS is found near the bottom of the sheet, in the media queries.

Problem I'm trying to solve (pic) - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/ipad-text_zpss35j9ty4.png

This is what happens when I use transform trick (pic) - 
http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/ipad-text-middle-page_zps1srfn7bq.png

HTML -

```
<section id="about" ng-controller="aboutController">    
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row about-row">

      <div class="about-left col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      </div>

      <div class="about-right col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="about-content">
          <div class="about-content-title">
            <h1><strong>I'M JAY.</strong></h1>
          </div>

          <div class="about-content-info">
            <p ng-if="about.firstParagraph">An entrepenurial minded, Full Stack Developer. Whenever I'm up against a challenge that I care about, it gives me a rush. Focusing on the big picture is important to me, but I never forget the smaller details. Anything that is not challenging is boring, and makes me yawn. Anything that is seemingly impossible interests me a lot. I'm read to get to work.</p>

            <p ng-if="!about.firstParagraph">Currently seeking a Javascript position, using the MEAN stack, in New York City. Being innovative, ambitious, and hard working are values that are very important to me. I want to join a company that has similar values and has goals of reaching ridiculous levels of success, not just modest realistic ones. I love working with a solid team.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="about-button">
            <button ng-if="about.firstParagraph" class="label label-success" ng-click="about.switchParagraph()">MORE =></button>
            <button ng-if="!about.firstParagraph" class="label label-success"><a href="/portfolio">VIEW SKILLS</a></button>
          </div>

          <div class="about-personal-info">
            <h4>Email: jaybittner@gmail.com</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="about-icon">
            <a href="{{ profile.url }}" ng-repeat="profile in about.profiles"><img ng-src="{{ profile.icon }}" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

CSS -

```
#about {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,97,65,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,97,65,1)), color-stop(7%, rgba(54,135,95,1)), color-stop(22%, rgba(36,123,85,1)), color-stop(53%, rgba(0,97,65,1)), color-stop(76%, rgba(34,121,84,1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(54,135,95,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(54,135,95,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#006141', endColorstr='#36875f', GradientType=1 );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #101010;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

#about .container-fluid, #about .row {
  height: 100%;
}

.about-left {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../../images/jay-ocean.jpg'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-right: 3px solid #101010;
}

.about-right {
  padding-top: 24vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-content {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.about-content-title h1{
  font-size: 3.1vw;
  margin-bottom: 0.6vh;
}

.about-content-info p {
  font-size: 1vw;
  word-spacing: 0.3vw;
  margin-bottom: 0.7vh;
}

.about-button button {
  margin-bottom: -0.1vh;
}

.about-personal-info h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0.7vh;
}

.about-button button {
  color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #101010;
  background-color: #101010;
  font-size: 0.7vw;
}

.about-button a {
  color: gray;
}

.about-personal-info h4 {
  font-size: 1vw;
  word-spacing: 0.3vw;
}

.about-icon img {
  height: 3.5vh;
  width: 1.75vw;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #101010;
  margin: 3px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .about-left {
    height: 50%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  }

  .about-right {
    padding-top: 0;
  }

  .about-content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 70%; 
  }

  .about-content-title h1 {
    font-size: 5vw;
  }

  .about-content-info p {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }

  .about-button button {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }

  .about-personal-info h4 {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }

  .about-icon img {
    height: 3vh;
    width: 3vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: It might have something to do with `.about-content` having `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `position:fixed` for your `.about-content` class. This aligns your content relative to the browser window, NOT relative to it's parent. So, if your page could scroll, that text would stay fixed in the middle of the browser's screen.

To fix this, change your `.about-content` class to use `position: absolute` instead. And you'll also need to set `position: relative` on the parent element that you want it to be set relative to because a `position:absolute` element will position itself relative to it's closest positioned ancestor.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fposition for descriptions of the various position values.

Comment: Did this but it's still getting stuck in the same spot^.

Comment: Got it to work. The issue was that I didn't have a specific height/width set on the parent element. Working great now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify clear positions for parent and child div to ensure expected vertical aligning effect. Just replace your css as follows.

```
.about-right {
  position: relative; // added this line
  padding-top: 24vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-content {
  position: absolute; // added this line
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

...
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  ...

  .about-right {
    position: relative; // added this line
    padding-top: 0;
  }

  .about-content {
    position: absolute; // added this line
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 70%; 
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I did the above but it's still getting stuck in the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

You are overthinking this...but the issues with your current css are:

As mentioned above position fixed is relative to viewport. Transform moves the element from its position.

What would be a much more elegant solution is to position the div using `inline-block` which is what i think you were trying to achieve in the first place with `text-align: center`

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eufqy08o/1/

```
    .about-left {
      min-height: 35vw;
      min-width: 100%;
      background-image: url('http://herbadmother.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/rotator/sample-1.jpg'); 
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
      background-size: cover;
      border-right: 3px solid #101010;
    }

    .about-right {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .about-content {
      width: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }

     /*in your media query dont set position!!*/
    .about-content {

    }
```

Comment: What I'm seeing in the fiddle is that you're making the image smaller and the area to write the text bigger. Not totally understanding the display: inline-block part, since I only have one element. What am I missing?

Comment: http://s988.photobucket.com/user/jtbitt/media/ipad-text_zpss35j9ty4.png.html this is what you wanted to achieve? inline-block when used with a parent div with text align center will center the element horizontally without having to use position absolute as position absolute moves the div outside the document flow

Comment: btw the image and text size is inmaterial, it was just a example. you can obviously change it!